# Getting Exception - java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0

I am new to JPA. I am trying to create EJB 3.0 + JPA (Hibernate) application. When I'm persisting data into database, I'm getting below exception.

**SessionBean method**

```
@PersistenceUnit private EntityManagerFactory emf;

@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void insterCustomerDetails(Customer customer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        //System.out.println("properties:::"+em.getProperties());
        //System.out.println("Model :::"+em.getMetamodel());
    System.out.println("Name ::::" + customer.getName() + "::customer id ::"+customer.getCustomer_id()+"::email::"+customer.getEmail_id()+"::address::"+customer.getAddress()+
            ":::ph number::"+customer.getPhNumber());
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
    et.begin();
    em.persist(customer);
    et.commit();
    em.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

**Persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="RetailUnit" >
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <!-- the JNDI data source-->
    <jta-data-source>java/customer</jta-data-source>
    <properties> 
        <!-- if this is true, hibernate will print (to stdout) the SQL it executes, 
            so you can check it to ensure it's not doing anything crazy
             <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/company;create=true" />
          <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user" />
          <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="123" /> -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <!-- since most database servers have slightly different versions of the 
            SQL, Hibernate needs you to choose a dialect so it knows the subtleties of 
            talking to that server -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <!-- this tell Hibernate to update the DDL when it starts, very useful 
            for development, dangerous in production -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Exception**

```
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.getTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:985)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.getTransaction(EntityManagerWrapper.java:857)
    at retail.ejb.service.CustomerSessionBeanImpl.insterCustomerDetails(CustomerSessionBeanImpl.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:206)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
    at $Proxy248.insterCustomerDetails(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:241)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
    at retail.ejb.service.__CustomerSessionBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.insterCustomerDetails(retail/ejb/service/__CustomerSessionBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    at retail.ejb.service._CustomerSessionBeanRemote_Wrapper.insterCustomerDetails(retail/ejb/service/_CustomerSessionBeanRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at retail.web.mbean.CustomerMB.createCustomer(CustomerMB.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If used inside an EJB, you do not need to use a transaction manually - all methods are transactional per default - you even have the `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)` on your method, which is the default setting.

The transaction begins on method start, if no transaction is available and is committed on method return. No manual transaction control required.

If you do not have a compelling reason to use the `EntityManagerFactory`, it is probably better to inject the `EntityManager` proper instead of retrieving it from the EMF on each call:

```
@PersistenceContext 
private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: i done code changes according to your suggestion, but getting the same exception again. i have provided the updated code please check.

Comment: Iam sorry.. i havent deployed right ear. i deployed again, its working now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @developer - let me restate please - the new code causes an Exception with the message `A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()` on `em.persist`? This would be very strange since the code looks right and you are actually not calling `getTransaction`. The EJB is properly annotated I assume?

Comment: @developer - ah good, I was doubting my logic already :) You're welcome

Comment: sorry for letting you trouble. Its working, i not deployed rite ear file. i redeployed the correct ear file. Now its working